# OrderBy nullable properties in a generic list throwing InvalidCastException

Tags: .net, vb.net, lambda, nullable

I need to return an a generic list in the correct order for my project, and I'm getting InvalidCastException errors.  Here is the code:

```
Dim lDt As List(Of Comment) = RemapCommentsForE1(so.CommentList). _
OrderBy(Function(x) x.CreateDate.Value). _
ThenBy(Function(x) x.Sequence). _
ThenBy(Function(x) x.SubSequence)
```

Note that:

- CreateDate is a `Nullable(Of DateTimeOffset)`
- Sequence is a `Nullable(Of Int32)`
- SubSequence is a `Nullable(Of Int32)`

The exact error I'm getting is:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`2[DTDataUploader.Comment,System.Int32]'
>   to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DTDataUploader.Comment]'.

I've tried converting to the actual types...

```
Dim lDt As List(Of Comment) = RemapCommentsForE1(so.CommentList). _
OrderBy(Function(x) x.CreateDate.Value). _
ThenBy(Function(x) Convert.ToInt32(x.Sequence)). _
ThenBy(Function(x) Convert.ToInt32(x.SubSequence))
```

... but I get the same error.  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LINQ operations like `Where` and `OrderBy` produce *queries*, not *results*. As the error states, the result of your full LINQ expression is an `OrderedEnumerable(Of DTDataUploader.Comment, System.Int32)`, not a list.

To turn this into a list, add a call to `ToList()` to the end of the expression.

```
Dim lDt As List(Of Comment) = RemapCommentsForE1(so.CommentList). _
OrderBy(Function(x) x.CreateDate.Value). _
ThenBy(Function(x) x.Sequence). _
ThenBy(Function(x) x.SubSequence).ToList()
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  I've done this a bunch in the past, so I'm not sure why I didn't catch that... but your super-fast response means I won't miss my deadline, which is just four hours away.

Answer (score 0):

The result of the query is an `OrderedEnumerable`, just add `.ToList()` at the end to realise the result as a list.